# React 0.14.7 vs 15.4.0

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between React 0.14.7 and 15.4.0?

I'm working on a React app that the previous developer started. In package.json I see that the app is set to using React ^0.14.7 but when I just put the quotes, Visual Studio is showing 15.4.0 as the latest stable version. This seems like a really big difference in version numbers. I feel like I'm missing something here.

A related question: how do I check the actual version being used? I went into npm_modules folder and checked React package but couldn't really tell the version number.

UPDATE:
Here's the pagkage.json file for React module under npm_modules:

[image]

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/02/19/new-versioning-scheme.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the release notes to get a feel for the breaking changes. If the code is still in development, it would probably make sense to attempt the upgrades. If it's in production currently, it could still be beneficial, but don't just blindly update it. Carefully read the notes. It would be wise to do partial updates gearing up to the latest stable release.

[React release notes beginning with `0.14.7`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0147-january-28-2016).

[This article explains the `0.15.0` bump](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/02/19/new-versioning-scheme.html).

To your second question, find the `package.json` file in the `node_modules/react` directory. The **2nd to last** line should indicate the version.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just updated the original post with what's in package.json for React. Is it the id field that tells me the version being used? Is it 0.14.8 according to this screen shot?

Comment: Updated my post... 2nd to last line :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you!